# Gitlab : increase number of characters in personal access token

Tags: gitlab

In Gitlab, when I read https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html, it seems that the number of characters for a personal access token is 20.

> The token string must be 20 characters in length, or it will not be recognized as a personal access token.

In Github, the pat is a 40 characters token.

In my ecosystem, I have both applications and I use a proxy in order to analyze what passes through the server. I use the length of the password being transferred in order to assess whether a user is using his password or his token in order to access Git. It would be simpler for me if Gitlab could use a token with the same length as github, i.e. 40 characters instead of 20.

Is it possible to tune Gitlab so that the personal access token is longer than 20 ?
My guess is probably not but someone might have found a trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length seems fixed, according to the [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html)

That differs from GitHub which:

- is 40
- is changing from `[a-f0-9]` to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`
- will support tokens up to 255 characters after June 1, 2021.

(See "[GitHub Authentication token format updates](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-03-04-authentication-token-format-updates/)")

Maybe GitLab will at some point follow suit, but for now (S1 2021), that is not the case

---

Note: [GitLab 14.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/11/22/gitlab-14-5-released/#new-gitlab-access-token-prefix-and-detection) (November 2021)

> ### New GitLab access token prefix and detection
>
> With GitLab 14.5 we have updated the GitLab [Personal Access Tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) and [Project Access Tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html) to include a standard prefix, `glpat-` by default for both GitLab.com and GitLab self-managed instances.
> We’ve also updated our Secret Detection scanning to detect this new pattern which will help protect you against accidentally leaked GitLab access tokens in commits.
>
> This improvement helps make it easy to detect GitLab tokens leaked in commits and builds on [community contribution](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/20968) improvements added in Gitlab 13.7 that [allowed Admins to set Personal Access Token prefixes at the instance level](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/account_and_limit_settings.html#personal-access-token-prefix), shoutout to @max-wittig and @dlouzan at Siemens for this contribution!
>
> Existing access tokens will not be modified but any new tokens will follow this new pattern or the custom pattern set by your self-hosted GitLab instance.
>
> If you would like to detect GitLab Personal Access Tokens and Project Access Tokens you can use the following regex detection pattern: `glpat-[0-9a-zA-Z\-]{20}`.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_5/14-5-admin-token-prefix.png -- New GitLab access token prefix and detection]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/273604).

---

As a result (Jan. 2023): "[Secret Detection update: Leaked Personal Access Tokens will soon be revoked](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2023/01/04/pat-revocation-coming-soon/) "

> GitLab will soon begin automatically revoking Personal Access Tokens ([PATs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens/)) when GitLab [Secret Detection](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/secret_detection/) finds them in public repositories, an update that will better protect GitLab users and organizations.

Comment: Yes. Things have not changed so far and still fixed at 20 for gitlab and 40 for Github